# localhost wordpress failed load style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, localhost

I'm trying to build WordPress theme in localhost. I have my functions.php when I open the browser (http://localhost/website/wordpress) this does not load all the css changes. Only the body background shows in the browser. what do you think the problem is? appreciate your help.

This is functions.php code:

```
<?php 
function load_stylesheets()
{

    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap'); 

    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');

function include_jquery(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js','',1,true);

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');

function loadjs(){
    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri().'js/script.js', '', 1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');
```

---

This is header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php wp_head();?>


</head>
<body <?php body_class();?>>

<header class="sticky-top">
</header>
```

---

This is front-page.php

```
<?php get_header();?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
left side
</div>

<div class="col">
Right side
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

---

style.css

```
body
{ 
    background: hsl(0, 64%, 98%);
}
header .hh
{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

even js alert does not load  this is the code ( just for test )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('test');


});
```

---

Comment: Please provide some code and what you've tried, so we can help you better. Thanks. :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code you're working on? It would be much easier to diagnose the problem :-)

Potential causes of the problem that come to my mind are:

- wp searches for the file, but the css file is not there
- css may be cached (solution: a lot of ctrl+f5 or clearing the cache)
- some typo in the css-enqueuing code

I may be wrong, but - as I said - it's har to tell without seeing the code. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. I tried to clear cache from chrome settings clear browsing data. still the problem.

Comment: OK, the css-enqueuing code looks OK. Make sure the files exist - look into the html source in your browser, find the <link> element and copy the url to your css file and paste it in the browser - you should see your css, otherwise the file is not there.

Comment: If the file is in place, make sure it doesn't cache. I do it this way:

$debug_suffix = constant( 'WP_DEBUG' ) ? '?v=' . time() : '';

$the debug_suffix variable contains current timestamp, or, if WP_DEBUG constant is set to false, is empty. The former represents the dev environment, the latter - production.
Then I append this variable to the css url passed to wp_register_style.

As the timestamp changes every second, the css url is never fetched from the cache (cause it's different each time I reload the page) so I always get the latest CSS.

Same strategy applies to JS enqueueing.

Comment: One important thng: remember to set the WP_DEBUG constant to false when you publish the site ;-)
It's defined in wp-config.php

Comment: Thank you to help me in this.
- I checked the link and the file is exist.  
- I updated the config.php file : 

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
 
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
until now, the browser does not load all css.
------
I could not understand the part of passing to wp_register_style if you could shed lights on this. Thank you appreciate it.

Comment: wp_register_style is a function, it works on data called "arguments". When you call the function in your code, you write its name and then put the arguments in brackets after the function name. This is called "passing the arguments" to the function call :-)

Comment: BTW, does the bootstrap style load?
Anyway, you can try a simpler approach: don't use wp_register_style, instead pass its arguments to wp_enqueue_style like this:
`wp_enqueue_style('my-basic-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css', array(), false, 'all');`
You can also replace the style's id (first argument) with something less obvious - just in case ;-) I used "my-basic-style" in the example above.

Comment: I have not changed the wp_register. I just  add extra code in css as well as in front-page.php. I correct the path of script.js file in functions.php I add only forwardslash  / in the beginning of the path . Now all it works fine. Thanks mpdoctor I appreciate your help. Have a nice day!